# How to connect my android app to the remote web server

Tags: android

I am working on an android app. Right now i am requesting a webserver and getting the data successfully.

Now the thing when i am running the server and my mobile device on the same network it's working fine. But when my webserver is running on one network for ex. WLAN and android device the Network 3G is enabled my app is not able to make the request.

So how can I make my webserver request visible to all the different networks.

on the android part i am making retrofit request like this to the server.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://134.162.1.120:3000") // This is the ip of my system (just random ip for illustration purpose)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
```

I am getting the data successfully when my PC and android device are on the same network. 
But when my phone and PC are on different network it's not getting connected

The server is on my local PC..

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: @KristyWelsh ...  I have added the snippets...

Comment: I think it's not even related to android. If your server runs on your machine, then it won't be visible outside your network. The easiest way is to run it somewhere in the cloud.

Comment: Ok Thank u guys for ur reply ... now i got a clear picture where i am doing the mistakes..

Comment: Is that IP address your LAN or public IP address? If public, have you enabled port forwarding on your router (port 80 in this case I imagine)? Can you run a port scanner (various free ones out there. just google them) on your ip and see if they can access it?

Comment: @kha .. hey I run the port scanner and i am getting result like this.. what does it means..     80/tcp filtered http
443/tcp open https

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your server is in your local LAN which you can access from your mobile device if it is in the same network via WLAN. You are accessing the server by it's LAN-IP. But you can't access this IP from outside of your LAN (from the internet) which is the case if you are using 3g on your mobile device.

Now what can you do? Find out the 'external' IP of your server which is visible on the internet and use this in your app. But be aware that you should have a static IP which often is not the case. You could also host your webservice on any professional webhosting service.

Comment: ...I tried with my public IP and just replaced with my LANIP .. but this is not getting connected to my webservice ... does it has to do something with network provider

Comment: You should be able to reproduce this from any machine in your LAN using the public IP. Try to connect to your service with the public IP. Maybe the port 3000 is to exposed by your firewall or router.

Comment: i ran the port scanner i am getting messages like this..80/tcp filtered http
443/tcp open https  ... Does it is preventing me to make http request

Comment: In your code you are using port 3000 so you should test that port.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using a local IP instead of an external one and that's where the problem lies. Replace the URL with your server's public IP address. You will be able to communicate with your server from both LAN and WAN.